# Correct Time Series Dates Label

Tags: r, time, series, forecasting

I have a time series with 5-minute observations over 2 months, I would like to plot it such that I can see the dates on the X axis, but I am getting a bunch of numbers instead. The data starts from the 2018-01-01 00:01:10 and ends with 2018-02-28 23:54:57. This is what I  have done using multiseasonal ts function (forecasting Package)
`bow_ts=msts(bow , seasonal.periods = c(288,24,7), start= c(2018,1,1), end=c(2018,2,28))
plot(bow_ts)`
and using ts from the forecast package: `ts(bow, frequency=c(24*60/5), start=c(2018,1,1), end=c(2018,2,28) )`

In both cases I am not able to get the dates labelled on the x-axis. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ts is not applicable to that sort of series.  It is used mainly for monthly and quarterly series.

Comment: Try using the tsibble package (or xts, or zoo).